# Reset global variables during python unit testing runtime

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing

I am currently writing tests for a bit of Python (using the 3.5 version) software for the company I'm working with, but am stumbling upon a problem which I currently believe is because of *global variables* if I could call it that.

The software architecture is extremely modular, hence to test individual modules a separate test file (perhaps called `test_somemodule_py`) is created containing one class that extends the `unittest.TestCase` one.

**NOTE** that what I call `modules` here is not really a Python module, but rather an application module

All of the tests are triggered through a single runner script which contains a custom loader:

```python
def load_tests(loader, tests, pattern):
suite = unittest.TestSuite()
for all_tests in loader.discover('tests', pattern='test_*.py'):
    for test_suite in all_tests:
        suite.addTests(test_suite)

return suite
```

During actual runtime all of the individual modules are held (contained) in a master like wrapper, which is basically a Singleton.

Now my problem is that whenever I run the tests as individual files (changing the loader from `test_*.py` to `test_somemodule.py`), all tests succeed, however if they are run all together (leaving the `test_*.py` pattern), some of the tests start failing.

I am pretty sure it was never the case when I hadn't implemented the master wrapper as a singleton, but the application functionality and architecture really requires that kind of approach. Since I am suspecting that only one instance of it is created, can anyone advise me on how to best solve this issue?

My theory is that if there was a method to *reset all 'globals' to an initial state*, it would work like a charm. Or perhaps there is some sort of method to isolate memory which is then discarded when test goes out of scope.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I may be way off here, but are you using the setup and teardown methods in your tests?

Comment: I am. However I am not really utilising them for the case I described in my question. The big issue is that I'm not sure if what I'm trying to achieve is at all possible and if it is - I am not sure how. Documentation is plenty, but looking for the answer is a bit like searching for a needle in a Pystack.

Comment: maybe try using PyTest, put all of your tests in one module called test_them_all.py or somting like that, that way each test is it's own scope.

Comment: for more info : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27954702/unittest-vs-pytest

Comment: depending on strcuture of ur code, choose `setUp, setUpClass, setUpModule or fixture`, detail [nose] (https://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/writing_tests.html#test-classes)

Comment: Thanks guys, will do some more reading and see if I can come up with anything

Answer (score 1):

Why not do this?

```
for name in dir():
    if not name.startswith('_'):
        del globals()[name]
```